# Category 'Newly Registered Websites' denied by WebBlocker policy 'WebBlocker.1'

Tags: centos, ssl

I have recently made public a website. I used 'dehydrated' (https://github.com/lukas2511/dehydrated) to create SSL certificates and it works fine as long as my URL is 'https://example.com' but I get the "Category 'Newly Registered Websites' denied by WebBlocker policy 'WebBlocker.1'." error whenever my URL misses the HTTPS:// part. My .htaccess file does redirect to https://example.com

Is there a certain time I should wait for? Is there anything in my configuration that causes the problem?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything in my configuration that causes the problem?

The block page isn't shown by your web server and has nothing to do with SSL specifics. It is shown *by your local network* (a site-blocking/content-filtering proxy server), and the server's .htaccess file isn't even being reached.

Of course, when you use HTTPS, the filtering proxy can no longer see the complete request (only the domain name), nor can it alter the webpage to show the message. So you end up bypassing the block, possibly because the proxy treats it as a low-risk category, or possibly because the proxy is unable to block HTTPS at all.

> Is there a certain time I should wait for?

As the error message hints, your LAN uses Watchguard WebBlocker software. According to its [documentation](https://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/help-center/en-US/Content/en-US/Fireware/services/webblocker/webblocker_categories_websense_c.html), domains stay in this blocking category for 41 days.

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful.